# Embedding QGIS Python Script in C++(Qt Creator)

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-processing

Is there any way that I can embed and use QGIS Processing algorithm written in python on Qt Creator using C++. If so how can I share the layer and other instances created in C++ with the embedded Python script. E.g  generate a grid programmatically in Python

```
import processing
layer = canvas.layer(0)
cellsize = 1000
input = processing.getobject(layer.name())
centerx = (input.extent().xMinimum() + input.extent().xMaximum()) / 2
centery = (input.extent().yMinimum() + input.extent().yMaximum()) / 2
width = (input.extent().xMaximum() - input.extent().xMinimum())
height = (input.extent().yMaximum() - input.extent().yMinimum())
grid="/yourpath/grid.shp"
processing.runandload("qgis:creategrid", cellsize, cellsize, width, height, centerx, centery, 1, input.crs().authid(), grid)
```

How can I display the grid result drawn by the processing algorithm in the canvas created in c++.